# Spark Streaming DStream.reduceByKeyAndWindow doesn't work

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using Apache Spark streaming to do some real-time processing of my web service API logs. The source stream is just a series of API calls with return code. And my Spark app is mainly doing aggregation over the raw API call logs, counting how many API returning certain HTTP code.

The batch interval on the source stream is 1 seconds. Then I do :

```
inputStream.reduceByKey(_ + _) where inputStream is of type DStream[(String, Int)].
```

And now I get the result `DStream level1`. Then I do `reduceByKeyAndWindow` on `level1` over 60 seconds by calling

```
val level2 = level1.reduceByKeyAndWindow((a: Int, b: Int) => a + b, Seconds(60), Seconds(60))
```

Then I want to do further aggregation (say `level 3`) over longer period (say 3600 seconds) on top of `DStream level2` by calling

```
val level3 = level2.reduceByKeyAndWindow((a: Int, b: Int) => a + b, Seconds(3600), Seconds(3600))
```

My problem now is: I only get aggregated data on `level2`, while `level3` is empty.

My understanding is that `level3` should not be empty and it should aggregate over `level 2` stream.

Of course I can change to let `level3` aggregate over `level1`, instead of `level2`. But I don't understand why it is not working by aggregating over `level2`.

It seems to me that you can only do one layer of `reduceByKeyAndWindow` on the source stream. Any further layers of `reduceByKeyAndWindow` on top of previous streams reduced by key and window won't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it should be a bug in Spark Streaming.  Seems the Window operation of windowed stream does not work. Now I'm also investigating the reason. Will keep updated for any findings.

Similar Question:
[indows of windowed streams not displaying the expected results](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Windows-of-windowed-streams-not-displaying-the-expected-results-tt466.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering. It is indeed a bug and I've logged it as [SPARK-7326](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7326). I've also fixed it myself. See my pull request at [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/5871)