# Distinct Element across dstream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, dstream

I am working on window dstreams wherein each dstream contains 3 rdd with following keys:

```
a,b,c
b,c,d
c,d,e
d,e,f
```

I want to get only unique keys across all dstream

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
```

How to do it in spark streaming?

Comment: only for each window of (3-4) intervals? Or do you want all unique keys ever seen?

Comment: hello maasg, my application wouldn't be sending duplicates after the window of 4 mins. So, if "a" is appearing at time "t", there are chances that it can appear at "t+1","t+2","t+3" and "t+4"  not beyond that. Thank you for thinking about the solution,

Comment: I tried creating dstream window with some size and sliding window. and reduceByKey .Its helps in cutting down some percentage of duplicates at the cost of time. So for example: Window(2mins,2mins) :- will make dstream1  RDDs - (rdd1: a,b,c ; rdd2:b,c,d) and reduceByKey will output {a,b,c,d} but the next dstream2  RDDs - {rdd1:c,d,e ; rdd2:d,e,f} will output {c,d,e,f}. There are dups (c,d) between dstream1 and dstream2 .. My application delay is growing by 2mins here with some cut down in duplicates. This is not right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use a window of t+4 intervals to keep a count of "last recently seen keys" and use that to remove duplicates on the current interval.

Something in the lines of this:

```scala
// original dstream
val dstream = ??? 
// make distinct (for a single interval) and pair with 1's for counting
val keyedDstream = dstream.transform(rdd=> rdd.distinct).map(e => (e,1))
// keep a window of t*4 with the count of distinct keys we have seen
val windowed = keyedDstream.reduceByKeyAndWindow((x:Int,y:Int) => x+y, Seconds(4),Seconds(1))
// join the windowed count with the initially keyed dstream
val joined = keyedDstream.join(windowed)
// the unique keys though the window are those with a running count of 1 (only seen in the current interval) 
val uniquesThroughWindow = joined.transform{rdd => 
    rdd.collect{case (k,(current, prev)) if (prev == 1) => k}
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you @maasg!!! However, reduceByKeyAndWindow wasn't giving and "2"s for value not sure why. Hence, instead of 

val windowed = keyedDstream.reduceByKeyAndWindow((x:Int,y:Int) => x+y, Seconds(4),Seconds(1)) 

i had to do 
val windowed = keyedDstream.window(Seconds(4),Seconds(1).reduceByKey((x:Int,y:Int) => x+y )).

Comment: Probabay reduceByKeyAndWindow still doesnt work on dstreams http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961925/spark-streaming-dstream-reducebykeyandwindow-doesnt-work

Comment: what version of Spark are you using? I actually tested the approach before posting. It was more challenging than expected.

Comment: Spark version 1.6.0. Thank you for spending time